# Magnific Pop Up Gallery for Images not working

Tags: jekyll, gallery, image-gallery, magnific-popup

After over 2h trying to troubleshoot this myself, here I am - a newbie!

Issue: I'm trying to create a MAGNIFIC LIGHTBOX GALLERY (just like the example: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) but when you click on an image, it opens into a new page (so gallery doesn't work - see what's happening life [here](http://tests.loveiscreative.com/gallery)).

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="grid gallery popup-gallery" id="portfolio-grid">
  <div class="col-4_sm-6_xs-12">
    <a href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" ><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="casa"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4_sm-6_xs-12">
    <a  href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" ><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="casa"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4_sm-6_xs-12">
    <a  href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" ><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="casa"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4_sm-6_xs-12">
    <a href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" ><img src="" alt="casa"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.popup-gallery').each(function() { // the containers for all your galleries
    $(this).magnificPopup({
        delegate: 'a', // the selector for gallery item
        type: 'image',
        gallery: {
          enabled:true
        }
    });
});
});
```

Side notes/Requirements: I'm using Gridlex Flexbox for wrapping images in a grid and it's a dynamic website so images are uploaded via Jekyll.

Any clues?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome. In the console on your page, I'm seeing errors like `$ is not a function`. And when I look at the source of your page, it looks like the jquery.js is being called _after_ jquery.magnific-popup.js. I'm guessing that might be the problem?

Comment: OMG, such an easy fix. I did it and it worked. Thank you so much!